# Parsing multi line sentences from a file using regex

Tags: java, regex

For a file which has sentences like this:

```
He O O
does O O
, O O
however O O
, O O
have B-MWE_LVC B-MWE_LVC_VERB
an I-MWE_LVC O
affair I-MWE_LVC B-MWE_LVC_NOUN
with O O
Clotho B-NE_PER O
, O O
the O O
youngest O O
aspect O O
of O O
Fate B-NE_MISC B-NE_MISC_SB
. O O

This O O
is O O
both O O
awkward O O
and O O
intriguing O O
to O O
Norton B-NE_PER O
since O O
her O O
past O O
is O O
his O O
future B-SENT_BOUND O
. O O
```

I want to extract each sentence based on the regex pattern (. o o) which marks the end of each sentence. I have writen some code below to parse this but get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.gyan.siapp.coref.resolve.test.main(test.java:46)

Line 46 is: builder.append(strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(' ')));

My Code:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String  folderPath ="C:/Users/Desktop/Data_And_Sentences/wiki50.iob";

    Scanner file = null;
    try
    {
        file = new Scanner(new File(folderPath));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();

        String strLine;

        //Read File Line By Line

   Pattern matchExp = Pattern.compile ("(.*?)(. O O)");
        Matcher m = matchExp.matcher(strLine);

        while (file.hasNext())   
        {

            while (!m.find()){
                builder.append(strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(' ')));
                builder.append(" ");
            }

            sentences.add(builder.toString());

            }
            System.out.println(sentences);
           //return sentences;
    }
```

Is this the correct approach? Should I use some other structure than a String Builder to ensure enough memory? My guess is that the entire file is being read as one string hence I am getting this exception. Is that right?

Comment: Don't recompile the pattern each time, you need to do that only once outside the loop.  Also if you want help post the complete stack trace and indicate which statement in your code throws the exception.

Comment: @JimGarrison Edited code per your recommendation and have provided the entire error description. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to append the content to `builder` if there is a match? Remove `!` then, `while (m.find()){`

Comment: I _highly_ recommend that you step through the code in your debugger one line at a time to understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Scanner.next() by default finds and returns the next complete token divided by " " (Space). Hence, strLine will not contains any space then strLine.indexOf(' ') will return -1 and cause exception.
You should read the file line by line into one string. Then split them by your pattern. \n

```
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
    while(file.hasNext()) {
        input.append(file.nextLine());
    }
    String[] sentences = input.toString().split("\\.* O O");
```

Comment: This doesn't really help my case as I only want ot include the first word of each line and create a sentence. I don't want the additional tags and O O to be part of my output. This is the output that I am looking for "He does,however,have an affair with Clotho,the youngest aspect of Fate. next sentence......"

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if this will help you. The below code produces output as -

[He , He does , He does , , He does , however , He does , however , , He does , however , , He does , however , , He does , however , , He does , however , with , He does , however , with , He does , however , with , , He does , however , with , the , He does , however , with , the youngest , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her past , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her past is , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her past is his , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her past is his , He does , however , with , the youngest aspect of . This is both awkward and intriguing to since her past is his . ]

```
<code>
  public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String  folderPath ="C:/Users/Desktop/Data_And_Sentences/wiki50.iob";

        Scanner file = null;
        try
        {
            file = new Scanner(new File(folderPath));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();

        String strLine;
        //String sentence = "";
        //Read File Line By Line
        Pattern matchExp = Pattern.compile ("\\.* O O");
        while (file.hasNext())   
        {

            strLine = file.nextLine();
            System.out.println(strLine);
            Matcher m = matchExp.matcher(strLine);
            if(m.find()) {
                System.out.println(strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(" ")));
                builder.append(strLine.substring(0, strLine.indexOf(" ")));
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sentences);
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
        //return sentences;
    }
</code>
```

Comment: Please don't post a guess as an answer. The point of StackOverflow is to serve as a repository for _future_ readers.  A wrong guess does nobody any good.